# Error on adding multiple entitymanager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've created two datasources one for the local database and another for reading some data from different database. However on starting the server up the I get the following exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory2' defined in file [/home/pallav/91mobiles/community-api/dist/WEB-INF/classes/spring-config/spring-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: Answer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: Answer
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1335) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:525) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.3.Final.jar:4.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.3.Final.jar:4.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.3.Final.jar:4.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.3.Final.jar:4.3.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Below is my spring xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nm" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">

</bean>


<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${dbdriverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db-url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db-username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db-password}" />
    <!-- <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" /> <property name="minPoolSize" 
        value="1" /> <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" /> -->
</bean>


<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource2">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${dbdriverClassName2}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db-url2}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db-username2}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db-password2}" />
    <!-- <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" /> <property name="minPoolSize"
        value="1" /> <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" /> -->
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory2">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit2" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager2">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory2" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:property-files/config-info.properties" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager2"/>
</beans>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/home/pallav/community-api/indexes" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit2"
                  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/home/pallav/community-api/indexes" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and below is the entity

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="persistenceUnit")
@Entity
public class Answer implements BaseEntity{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
private Question question;

private String description;

private int likes;

private int spam;

private int comments;

private short status;
- - -
```

I don't want the `Answer` table to be there in the second database. 
Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is what I did in order to segregate the Entities based on the persistence units.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.nm.community.entities.Question</class>
    <class>com.nm.community.entities.Answer</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/home/pallav/community-api/indexes" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy" />
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="../community-api/indexes" /> -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit2"
                  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.nm.community.entities.MasterProductEntity</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/home/pallav/community-api/indexes" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy" />
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="../community-api/indexes" /> -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Each persistence unit is provided with the names of the classes on which the `datasource` would look for while server is getting up. Also, `<exclude-unlisted-classes>` should be `true`.